# Serving data with Ring and Compojure

Tags: json, clojure, compojure, ring

I am configuring and setting up a web application to serve the JSON data http://www.ericrochester.com/clj-data-analysis/data/census-race.json file statically.

My dependencies:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2197"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.1.7"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.7"]
                 [compojure "1.1.3"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.2"]
                 [lein-cljsbuild "0.2.10"]]
```

As the title says I'm using Ring as a development plugin, i.e.

```
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.3"]]
```

The Leiningen project is

```
   (ns test-app.core
   (:require [compojure.route :as route]
             [compojure.handler :as handler]
             [clojure.string :as str])
   (:use compojure.core
             ring.adapter.jetty
             [ring.middleware.content-type :only
             (wrap-content-type)]
             [ring.middleware.file :only (wrap-file)]
             [ring.middleware.file-info :only
             (wrap-file-info)]
             [ring.middleware.stacktrace :only
             (wrap-stacktrace)]
             [ring.util.response :only (redirect)]))
```

and in the project.clj

```
  :ring {:handler test-app.core/app}
```

which I am not sure if this will tell Ring where the web application
is.

Moreover, I am not sure how to serve the JSON data file statically. I have read that "Ring serves static files out of the /resources directory of your project. In this case, create the directory /resources/data and put the data file that you downloaded from http://www.ericrochester.com/clj-data-analysis/data/census-race.json into it."

It is mostly this last part about creating the **/resources/data** directory where I am lost in the implementation. Could someone show how this part is done?

If I can learn to get past this I am looking to build routes and handlers, i.e.

```
  (defroutes site-routes
     (GET "/" [] (redirect "/data/census-race.json"))
     (route/resources "/")
     (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

and

```
 (def app
    (-> (handler/site site-routes)
    (wrap-file "resources")
    (wrap-file-info)
    (wrap-content-type)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and in the project.clj
>
> :ring {:handler test-app.core/app}
>
> which I am not sure if this will tell Ring where the web application
>   is.

When you run `$ lein ring server-headless` it will look for `app` in the `test-app.core` namespace. You should have something like the following in your `core.clj` file:

```
(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))
```

> It is mostly this last part about creating the /resources/data
>   directory where I am lost in the implementation. Could someone show
>   how this part is done?

In the root of your project directory you should have a `resources` folder. Create a `data` folder inside the `resources` folder.

I'm not sure what problem you're having?

Comment: I've created the folder `data` within `resources` but am not sure how to download http://www.ericrochester.com/clj-data-analysis/data/census-race.json to it... @deadghost

Comment: @sunspots Right-click -> save-page-as?

Answer (score 1):

If your project looks like this:

```
project.clj
src/test_app/core.clj
resources/public/data/census-race.json
```

Then the your `site-routes` handler will serve up that JSON file when you request the path `/data/census-race.json`.

You don't need any of the extra middleware like `wrap-file`, `wrap-file-info`, or `wrap-content-type`, since `compojure.route/resources` already does everything you need.

Comment: I'm not sure how to put `census-race.json` into the path `resources/data` @JohnCromartie